# Adding a tkinter scrollbar to a treeview without any space

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, scrollbar

I am trying to add a scrollbar to a treeview in tkinter, but the scrollbar is visually detached from the treeview. Put differently, there is a small space in between the scrollbar and the treeview. How do I configure the scrollbar such that it is completely attached (visually) to the treeview?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import functions


headers = {
 'accept': '*/*',
 'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
 'accept-language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,hi;q=0.7,la;q=0.6',
 'cache-control': 'no-cache',
 'dnt': '1',
 'pragma': 'no-cache',
 'referer': 'https',
 'sec-fetch-mode': 'no-cors',
 'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
 'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36'
}


class View(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, title, size):
        super().__init__()

        # main setup
        self.title(title)
        self.geometry(f'{size[0]}x{size[1]}')
        self.resizable(False, False)

        # create frames
        self.url_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.url_frame.pack(pady=10)

        self.tree_frame = tk.Frame(self)
        self.tree_frame.pack(pady=10)

        # widgets
        Widgets(self.url_frame, self.tree_frame)

        # run
        self.mainloop()


class Widgets:
    def __init__(self, url_frame, tree_frame):
        self.product_url_label = ttk.Label(url_frame, text='Product URL:')
        self.product_url_label.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=20, sticky='w')

        self.product_url_stringvar = tk.StringVar()
        self.product_url_entry = ttk.Entry(url_frame, textvariable=self.product_url_stringvar, width=70)
        self.product_url_entry.grid(column=1, row=0, padx=10, columnspan=3, sticky='w')

        self.run_button = ttk.Button(url_frame, command=self.run_scraper, text='Run')
        self.run_button.grid(column=4, row=0, padx=20, sticky='w')

        self.product_label = ttk.Label(tree_frame, text='Product:')
        self.product_label.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=20, pady=20, sticky='w')

        self.scroll_bar = ttk.Scrollbar(tree_frame, orient="vertical")

        self.return_treeview = ttk.Treeview(tree_frame, columns=('ID', 'Date', 'Time', 'Price', 'Change'), yscrollcommand=self.scroll_bar.set)
        self.return_treeview.column("#0", width=0, stretch=False)
        self.return_treeview.heading("#0", text="", anchor='center')
        self.return_treeview.column('ID', anchor='center', width=100)
        self.return_treeview.heading('ID', text='ID', anchor='center')
        self.return_treeview.column('Date', anchor='center', width=196)
        self.return_treeview.heading('Date', text='Date', anchor='center')
        self.return_treeview.column('Time', anchor='center', width=196)
        self.return_treeview.heading('Time', text='Time', anchor='center')
        self.return_treeview.column('Price', anchor='center', width=196)
        self.return_treeview.heading('Price', text='Price', anchor='center')
        self.return_treeview.column('Change', anchor='center', width=196)
        self.return_treeview.heading('Change', text='Change', anchor='center')
        self.return_treeview.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=6, padx=20, sticky='nsew')

        self.scroll_bar.grid(column=6, row=1, sticky='nsew')
        self.return_treeview.config(yscrollcommand=self.scroll_bar.set)
        self.return_treeview.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    def run_scraper(self):
        url_path = self.product_url_stringvar.get()
        if not url_path == "":
            url_data = functions.get_data(url_path, headers)
            parsed_data = functions.parse_data(url_data)
            print(parsed_data)
        else:
            pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    View("Coolblue Product Tracker", (950, 400))
```

I have already tried creating a separate frame for the treeview, but I still have the same problem as I do without the 2 separate frames.

Comment: Remove `padx=20` from `self.return_treeview.grid(...)`.

Comment: That works, but then the treeview is not aligned with the labels anymore. Is there anyway to ensure that everything is aligned (also between both frames)?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. There's a fair amount of code that is unrelated to the question being asked.

Comment: I added a tuple to denote the x-padding on the left and right side. This seems to work. Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

You're explicitly adding the space when you use `padx=20` in the following statement:

```
self.return_treeview.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=6, padx=20, sticky='nsew')
```

If you remove the padding, the space will go away. If you don't like how the tree aligns with the other widgets, add the padding when you call pack on `self.tree_frame`.

pro tip: when trying to solve layout problems, it's useful to temporarily give frames a visible border. For example, adding a border to `self.tree_frame` will help make it easy to see that the space was inside the frame rather than outside.